# VBA - Copy rows if columns contain different strings and group them

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with information about customers. In the 6th column one can find the customer names. I have a code that scans for certain customer names and if it matches the criteria it copies the whole row to a new worksheet.
So far so good. But I want the VBA script to "group" the customers between going to the next one.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub testcopy()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


aCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, aCol).End(xlUp).Row

destiny_row = 2
For x = 2 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer1") Then
    wsTarget.Rows(destiny_row).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
    destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
    End If
        If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer2") Then
    wsTarget.Rows(destiny_row).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
    destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
    End If
      If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer3") Then
    wsTarget.Rows(destiny_row).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
    destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
    End If
Next
```

This is what the code basically does:

[image]

I want it to further group the rows by customer.

Here is what I want it to do:

[image]

How would I go about doing that? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: is the sheet sorted by column F (customer)?

Comment: No, it is in random order.

Comment: Then I suggest to copy the desired rows as you already do to sheet2. Then sort sheet2 by column F so the customers that are going to be grouped stand together. And finally loop through column F cells from top to bottom and everytime the customer changes add a headline with the customer name.

Comment: @Peh - it should loop from bottom to top if rows are to be inserted.

Comment: @Jeeped yes both is possible. If you go from top to bottom with `for i = 1 to maxRow` and add rows then you obviously need to add +1 to the `maxRow` everytime you add a line. But bottom to top might be more intuitive.

Comment: @Peh - `maxRow` is locked as the extent of the increment as soon as you run the first line of `for i = 1 to maxRow` and cannot be changed. You might be able to increment a second counter but it's complicated and pointless when bottom-to-top will do.

Comment: @Jeeped Ah of course you need a `Do While i <= max` then. My bad :(

Comment: @Peh  So I was able to rewrite my code to get it to first scan for one customer, then leave a row empty, scan for next one etc. This rows are grouped by customers and between every group there is an empty row. 

[What it does now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0z4q.png)


     
 But I have absolutely no idea how to write a code that scans these groups and writes the respective customer name in the empty row in between.

Comment: You don't need to scan then. Just add the text instead of leaving the line blank. Or have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I shortened your copy script to an `OR` statement.
2. After the desired rows are copied to sheet2, the sheet is sorted by column F to group the customers.
3. The headlines for the customers are added. Therefore it loops through the column F and when ever the customer changes a headline is added.

---

```
Sub testcopy()
    Dim aCol As Long
    Dim MaxRowList As Long, destiny_row As Long, x As Long

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    aCol = 1
    MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, aCol).End(xlUp).Row

    destiny_row = 1
    For x = 2 To MaxRowList
        If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer1") Or _
           InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer2") Or _
           InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 6), "Customer3") Then

            wsTarget.Rows(destiny_row).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
            destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
        End If
    Next


    ' Sort by Customer column F
    With wsTarget.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F:F"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange wsTarget.UsedRange
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    ' Add the headlines for Customers
    Dim max_row As Long, i As Long
    Dim lastCustomer As String

    max_row = destiny_row
    i = 1
    lastCustomer = ""
    Do While i < max_row
        If wsTarget.Cells(i, "F").Value <> lastCustomer Then 'if current customer is different from last customer
            lastCustomer = wsTarget.Cells(i, "F").Value 'remember last customer
            wsTarget.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'add a row above
            wsTarget.Cells(i, 1).Value = lastCustomer 'write the customer as headline
            max_row = max_row + 1 'because we added a row the last row moved one row down
        End If
        i = i + 1 'goto next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Just had to add Sheets("Sheet2").Select before the headline adding begins as it did the headline adding to the currently opened sheet and not to Sheet2. Works like a charm now.

Comment: My bad :( Instead of `.Select` (select should not be used if possible because it slows Excel down) I suggest to use `wsTarget.` I changed my answer to correct this issue.